# JSON serialization of different attributes of a single entity for different requests using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-serialization

There are several REST calls that require the same JSON entity with a different set of attributes. Example of the entity:

```
public class JsonEntity
{
   public String id;
   public String name;
   public String type;
   public String model;
}
```

`JsonEntity` is a part of the complex responses of different calls. The first call requires the whole `JsonEntity` without changes. Second call requires `JsonEntity` without `type` and `model` attributes. Thrid one requires `JsonEntity` without `name` attribute.

Is there any way to retrieve the same JSON entity with a particular set of attributes depending on the particular context (except separating `JsonEntity`) using Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 ways of doing this:

**1. Use @JsonGetter**

This annotation tells jackson to use a metho rather than a field for serialization.
Create 3 subclasses of `JsonEntity`, one for each response. Change `JsonEntity` and use `@IgnoreField` on every field, make them `protected` if possible. On each subclasses, create specific getter for the fields you need, example:

```
public class JsonEntitySecondCall extends JsonEntity
{
  @JsonGetter("id")
  public String getId(){
    return id;
  }

 @JsonGetter("name")
 public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
}
```

Also, create a clone/copy constructor for `JsonEntity`. For your second call, create a new `JsonEntitySecondCall` by cloning the original `JsonEntity`, and use it in your API. Because of the anotation, the created Object will only serialisze the given fields. I don't this you can just cast your object, because Jackson uses reflection.

**2. Use @AnyGetter**

the AnyGetter annotaiton allows you to define a map of what will be serialized:

```
private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> properties() {
    return properties;
}
```

Now you just need to tell your `JsonEntity` what properties it needs to return before each call (you could create 3 methods, one for each context, and use an enum to set which one must be used.).

**3. Use @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)**

This annotation tells Jackson not to serialize a field if it is null. You can then clone your object and set null the fields you don't want to send. (this only works if you shouldn't send null elements to the API)

For more on Jackson annotations [use this link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-annotations.html).